# Why I can't use "that its" in this case?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, relative-pronouns, exam-questions

I faced a question where I was supposed to fill in the missing blank. The question was:

> The large family _____ house had been destroyed by the storm was invited to stay at a hotel.

There were multiple options including:

i) whose

ii) that its

Can someone explain why option (ii) is wrong while option (i) is correct?

What is the grammar involved here?

Comment: Because that's how the language works! We can say "The family _that lived_ in the house [that had been] destroyed...", but if there is no verb we have to say "The family _whose_ house..."

Comment: Duplicate of https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/230431/whose-vs-that-its-in-english

Answer (score 1):

I think OP's second version is a failed attempt at a [***cleft sentence***](https://www.really-learn-english.com/cleft-sentences.html). Simplifying, we have the non-idiomatic form...

> 1: *This is a sentence **which its** language is English.* (***its*** = possessive ***this sentence's***, not ***it is***)

...which is trying to fuse the two separate clauses / sentences...

> 2: *This is a sentence. **Its** language is English.*

The idiomatically correct way to join those two is...

> 3: *This is a sentence **whose** language is English*

---

Simplifying even more, we can remove the "possessive" element and consider...

> 4: *This is a sentence **which it is** written in English.* (NON-IDIOMATIC, as per OP's example #2)

...which non-idiomatically attempts to fuse...

> 5: *This is a sentence. **It is** written in English.*

The idiomatically correct versions are...

> 6a: *This is a sentence **which is** written in English*
>    6b: *This is a sentence **that is** written in English*
>    6c: *This is a sentence written in English* (the "relativising" element can validly be omitted entirely)
>    6d: *This is a sentence. **It is** written in English*

Note that whereas we can completely discard the "relativizing" element in #6c above, we can't do this with the *possessive* forms *(the **family's** house, the **sentence's** language)*.

---

I don't think there's a clear-cut *grammatical* justification for rejecting the syntax of my examples #1 and #4, which looks to me very similar to the subject of [this ELU question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/245363/what-is-the-name-of-the-grammatical-device-where-18th-and-19th-century-sentences). Essentially, what we have is "redundant relativizers" (the contextually-relevant *family / sentence* has already been referenced by the pronoun ***it***, so there's no need to reference it *again* using ***which, that***, or possessive ***whose***). It's just not idiomatic (today, at least, but I suspect such constructions *might* have been more acceptable a couple of centuries ago).

---

Thanks to @snailcar for suggesting that the constructions we're dealing with here involve (failed) attempts to use [***resumptive pronouns***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resumptive_pronoun). I'm not 100% sure, but I suspect the reason they fail is because they violate [***Ross Constraints***](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/ross.html) (as covered in that link by our very own [John Lawler](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/2893/john-lawler)).

Comment: You may want to look up *resumptive pronouns*.

Comment: Dang! I search for things like "superfluous / extraneous pronoun / relativizer", but found nothing useful. I'll include a reference, ty.